# Does the CF6 use Pneumatic Reverse Thrust from the APU's bleed air?

Tags: aircraft-design

Does the A330's engine (the [GE CF6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_CF6)) use only pneumatic power from the APU for reverse thrust? Please explain detailed. Sorry for my English.

Comment: So,what do you say exactly please explain

Comment: Then look at that   https://www.instagram.com/p/BR8n30DhliW/

Comment: Maybe pneumatic power are used only for tests not in flight?..on the video footage is from test

Comment: Okay , I'll research​ more exactly,thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

### Thrust reversers on high-bypass engines are airframe parts

The thrust reversers on a high-bypass turbofan such as the CF6 are treated as part of the nacelle, which is made by the airframer, as opposed to being part of the engine.  This is unlike target-type thrust reversers, which are treated as engine parts by and large.

### Airbus uses hydraulic reversers by and large

The reversers on current Airbii (including the A330 that you ask about) are hydraulic.  This is in contrast to the B747 and the A300/310 which also use the CF6 engine and use pneumatic reversers (driven from high stage engine bleed air directly, *not* the general bleed ducts).

Comment: Related [schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlZjR.png) in the [A330 FCOM](http://docslide.us/documents/aircraft-a330-power-plant.html), page 1-70-70 P1.

Comment: Why the two i's on Airbii? It would just be "Airbi"